# How to run Specific Thread of Jmeter from command line

Tags: multithreading, jmeter, load-testing

I am trying to run only specific threads of Jmeter at a time from command line.
I added an if controller in my test plan and in the condition block i wrote `${__P(threadActive)} == true` so that i can give the value of "threadActive" from the command line.
I did the same for other thread group and gave the condition `${__P(group)} == true`.

Now when I run want to run only one thread group I write
`JMeter -n -t "TestPlanName.jmx" -JthreadActive=true" or "JMeter -n -t "TestPlanName.jmx" -Jgroup=true`
to run only one thread it starts executing both of the threads. Where as when I change the conditions value in the condition block to false and write `JMeter -n -t "TsetPlanName.jmx" -JthreadActive=false` it executes that thread. 
Obviously this means the default value of these variables are true, so how do i change the default value of these user variables?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
  "${__P(threadActive)}" == "true"
```

With this:

- JMeter -n -t "TestPlanName.jmx" -JthreadActive=true

Comment: That's great. It worked :)
Now I have another issue.

Comment: I build a test plan on Jmeter and running that from maven.I don't know how to take those user defined variables from the cmd when I am running the test on maven that I have specified in Jmeter. For example I have defined the number of threads in jmeter with "${__P(users)}", or I have if controller condition to run the specific thread. And specified the if condition of if controller with "${__P(abc)}" == "true". So how do I take the values of abc or users from cmd line when I'm running the test with maven.
What should I include in my POM.xml file?
And how should I write the cmd statemen?

Comment: I cant up vote currently, I am very new here, I don't have the enough reputation.
Can you help me with my other issue please?

Comment: can you ask it within another question showing as much details as possible on your config ?

Comment: @UBIKLOADPACK
I have tried the above mentioned solution.
I have added two conditions , condition 1 and condition 2 with the following structure
>Thread 1(contition 1) 
     >Child Thread(condition 2)
>Thread 2

... and so on 
i am running the following command from cmd but i do not get any output into the specified output file

jmeter.bat-n-tC:\\pathtojmx\\testfile.jmx-lC:\\pathtooutput\\JMETER_OUTPUT.xml-Jcondition1=true-Jcondition=true

Could you help me out here in any way.